# GET request can be bookmarked and POST can not . Can anybody explain on this?

Tags: http

I am studying the HTTP methods. I read that GET request can be bookmarked and POST request can not be bookmarked.
Can anybody explain this with an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An HTTP POST *can* be bookmarked, but since a bookmark only consists of the URL, all of the form parameters will be lost. This will often mean that the web server doesn't know what to do with the request, since it was expecting some form parameters.

If you submit a form via a GET request, all of the form parameters go into the URL (after the ?), so a bookmark will contain all of the information needed for the webserver to rebuild the page a second time (except for cookies, perhaps, but a webserver is more likely to handle that gracefully)

Comment: Minor quibble: Since "bookmarked" has a strong implication of a browser, and browsers don't store the associated HTTP method with a bookmark, then a POST cannot really be bookmarked. The URL of a POST can be stored and executed as a repeated POST, but in my mind, that's distinct from a "bookmark."

Answer (score 12):

A POST cannot be bookmarked. Attempting to bookmark a POST will just result in a GET operation on the URL.
There's a very good reason for this, GET requests are supposed to be idempotent - that is, making the same GET request numerous times should result in the same response. POST requests on the other hand are not. 
Allowing POSTs to be bookmarked could result in you paying for something twice, transferring money out of your bank account again, etc.

Answer (score 8):

It is not that the one or other cannot be bookmarked. It is more that clicking a bookmark will **always** fire a `GET` request! Clicking a plain vanilla link, bookmark, browser nav button, entering browser address bar, etcetera all fires a `GET` request. They never fires a `POST` request. A `POST` request is *normally* only fired when you *submit* a HTML `<form>` which is set with `method="post"`. You can perfectly program software to bookmark a `POST` request, but it is not done so due to sensitive reasons.

The special thing here however is that a `GET` request is [**idempotent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). In other words, it is *guaranteed* to give the *same* result everytime when you invoke it. That is quite simple as all request parameters are just available in the request *URL*. You can use it to **preprocess** data prior to display. In Java Servlet world, you normally use `doGet()` method for this which preloads some stuff based on the request parameters at end forwards the request to a JSP file for display.

A `POST` request however is **not** idempotent. In other words, it is *not guaranteed* to give the same result everytime when you invoke it. All request parameters are included in the request *body*. It is not visible for the enduser and also not visible in the request URL. In other words, you cannot bookmark it. You can use it ro **postprocess** data after a form submit. In Java Servlet world, you normally use `doPost()` method for this which gathers the request parameters and stores it in some database and at end forwards *or* redirects the request to a JSP file for result/confirmation/display.

Comment: really well written. Does idempotence also include second request will be ignored until response of first request is delivered (in case of GET).

Answer (score 2):

In a `GET` request all the information for the request is encoded in the URL. In a `POST` request the request is made to the specified URL, but all the information related to the request, e.g. form content, is passed in the request body.

When you bookmark a URL you're only bookmarking the URL, not the request body. E.g. if you fill in a form on webpage that is then passed to the webserver as a `POST` request, and you then bookmark the response page in your browser, the browser will make note of only the URL, but not the form body.

Also, when you bookmark a page in a browser, the bookmark includes only the URL, but not the request method. The browser always uses `GET` for all bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact that's not requests are bookmarked but URIs.

GET parameters are sent as part of URL whereas POST parameters are sent in HTTP request body. POST is like GET with second hidden set of arguments that aren't visible to user. This is why you are able to make POST request on URL that contains GET parameters.
For details see [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Though normally bookmarks contain URLs, they may also contain JavaScript code (so named bookmarklets) and there are hacks to make bookmarks that would make POST request instead of GET.
For details see [How to save a bookmark in Firefox with POST data?](https://superuser.com/questions/182996/how-to-save-a-bookmark-in-firefox-with-post-data)