# How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, post, parameters, request, uri

In an HTTP **GET** request, parameters are sent as a ***query string***:

```
http://example.com/page?parameter=value&also=another
```

In an HTTP **POST** request, the parameters are not sent along with the URI.

***Where are the values?*** In the request header? In the request body? What does it look like?

Comment: "In an HTTP POST request, the parameters are not sent along with the URI." - though it can be (just theoretically), do not confuse other people. POST, in accordance to spec, MUST serve non-idempotent requests, but you can use request body (which is segregated from Headers by ONE empty line), as well as request parameters.

Answer (score 1454, accepted):

The values are sent in the request body, in the format that the content type specifies.

Usually the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the request body uses the same format as the query string:

```
parameter=value&also=another
```

When you use a file upload in the form, you use the `multipart/form-data` encoding instead, which has a different format. It's more complicated, but you usually don't need to care what it looks like, so I won't show an example, but it can be good to know that it exists.

Comment: I had forgot about file uploads being different (+1/accepted). Your answer is sufficient, while it would be extra nice if it had more info on `multipart/form-data`. For those interested though, here's [a question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

Comment: **NOTE**:  the body is separated from the header by just **one blank line**.

Comment: You explained what we place in the HTTPBody, but what do we place/write in the HTTPHeader? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @Honey: The HTTP header for a post looks like one for a get, but with the verb POST instead of GET, and a content type value (and an optional content length value) as the request has content (body). Every type of request has a header, some types also have a body.

Comment: Can you send JSON using this method?

Comment: @KennethWorden No, non of the methods will properly send JSON. you can however upload a json file in a form encoded with `multipart/form-data` or if you're in charge of request construction, change content-type to `application/json` and paste json text in http body directly

Comment: As far as encoding is concerned, the MDN docs state the possible values as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default), `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` (HTML5 only.) Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype

Comment: @Guffa What about other request types like PUT and delete ? Is this should be used for post requests ? If yes can we have any use case for this query?

Comment: Since the question explicitly states the opposite, it should be mentioned that POST-requests **may** have URL-encoded query parameters just like GET-requests. Although this might not be common practice this is effectively used: Stanford's [CoreNLP tools](http://corenlp.run). In that specific case, the query parameters even contain JSON-encoded values partially related to @KennethWorden 's comment.

Comment: The answer to the following question is also of interest. [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/452614)

Answer (score 482):

**Short answer:** in POST requests, values are sent in the "body" of the request. With web-forms they are most likely sent with a media type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Programming languages or frameworks which have been designed to handle web-requests usually do "The Right Thing™" with such requests and provide you with easy access to the readily decoded values (like `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` in PHP, or `cgi.FieldStorage()`, `flask.request.form` in Python).

---

Now let's digress a bit, which may help understand the difference ;)

The difference between `GET` and `POST` requests are largely semantic. They are also "used" differently, which explains the difference in how values are passed.

## GET ([relevant RFC section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1))

When executing a `GET` request, you ask the server for one, or a set of entities. To allow the client to filter the result, it can use the so called "query string" of the URL. The query string is the part after the `?`. This is part of the [URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

So, from the point of view of your application code (the part which *receives* the request), you will need to inspect the URI query part to gain access to these values.

Note that the keys and values are part of the URI. Browsers *may* impose a limit on URI length. The HTTP standard states that there is no limit. But at the time of this writing, most browsers *do* limit the URIs (I don't have specific values). `GET` requests should *never* be used to submit new information to the server. Especially not larger documents. That's where you should use `POST` or `PUT`.

## POST ([relevant RFC section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3))

When executing a `POST` request, the client is actually submitting a new *document* to the remote host. So, a *query* string does not (semantically) make sense. Which is why you don't have access to them in your application code.

`POST` is a little bit more complex (and *way* more flexible):

When receiving a POST request, you should always expect a "payload", or, in HTTP terms: a [message body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3). The message body in itself is pretty useless, as there is no *standard* (as far as I can tell. Maybe application/octet-stream?) format. The body format is defined by the `Content-Type` header. When using a HTML `FORM` element with `method="POST"`, this is usually `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Another very common type is [multipart/form-data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) if you use file uploads. But it could be *anything*, ranging from `text/plain`, over `application/json` or even a custom `application/octet-stream`.

In any case, if a `POST` request is made with a `Content-Type` which cannot be handled by the application, it should return a [`415` status-code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13).

Most programming languages (and/or web-frameworks) offer a way to de/encode the message body from/to the most common types (like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`). So that's easy. Custom types require potentially a bit more work.

Using a standard HTML form encoded document as example, the application should perform the following steps:

1. Read the `Content-Type` field
2. If the value is not one of the supported media-types, then return a response with a `415` status code
3. otherwise, decode the values from the message body.

Again, languages like PHP, or web-frameworks for other popular languages will probably handle this for you. The exception to this is the `415` error. No framework can predict which content-types your application chooses to support and/or not support. This is up to you.

## PUT ([relevant RFC section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4))

A `PUT` request is pretty much handled in the exact same way as a `POST` request. The big difference is that a `POST` request is supposed to let the server decide how to (and if at all) create a new resource. Historically (from the now obsolete RFC2616 it was to create a new resource as a "subordinate" (child) of the URI where the request was sent to).

A `PUT` request in contrast is supposed to "deposit" a resource exactly *at* that URI, and with *exactly* that content. No more, no less. The idea is that the *client* is responsible to craft the *complete* resource before "PUTting" it. The server should accept it *as-is* on the given URL.

As a consequence, a `POST` request is usually not used to *replace* an existing resource. A `PUT` request can do both create *and* replace.

## Side-Note

There are also "[path parameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)" which can be used to send additional data to the remote, but they are so uncommon, that I won't go into too much detail here. But, for reference, here is an excerpt from the RFC:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is considered
> opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications often use the
> reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit scheme-specific or
> dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For example, the semicolon (";")
> and equals ("=") reserved characters are often used to delimit parameters and
> parameter values applicable to that segment.  The comma (",") reserved
> character is often used for similar purposes.  For example, one URI producer
> might use a segment such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version
> 1.1 of "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
> indicate the same.  Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific
> semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific
> to the implementation of the URIs dereferencing algorithm.

Comment: I may have gone on a slight tangent indeed. I added a "tl;dr" to the top of the answer which should make it clearer.

Comment: I also just now edited it to reference RFC7231 instead of RFC2616 (which has been obsolete for a while). The main difference for this answer apart from the updated links, is in the "PUT" section.

Comment: I thought PUT was handled differently than POST since it's supposed to be idempotent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not

Comment: @rogerdpack You are not wrong. If you read the second paragraph in the `PUT` section, you will see that it *is* idempotent. `POST` in contrast can - by definition - not be. `POST` will always create a new resource. `PUT` will, if an identical resource exist replace it. So if you call `POST` 10 times, you will create 10 resources. If you call `PUT` 10 times, it will (maybe) create only one. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 474):

The content is put after the HTTP headers.  The format of an HTTP POST is to have the HTTP headers, followed by a blank line, followed by the request body.  The POST variables are stored as key-value pairs in the body.

You can see this in the raw content of an HTTP Post, shown below:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
```

You can see this using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), which you can use to watch the raw HTTP request and response payloads being sent across the wire.

Comment: Only if the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not always the case.

Comment: @ Camilo Martin .... [+1] for great question & @ Joe Alfano .... [+1] for great answer ....... i got a clear idea now about the POST request  .... but if a image comes along with key,value pair of data information ..... How does the structure of POST looks like ?

Comment: @Joe, Now why would you have a `From` header there?

Comment: @Joe, I love the random inclusion of the `From` header. IMO it's up there with the 418 HTTP status code.

Comment: how do you add a user and password authentication?

Answer (score 66):

You cannot type it directly on the browser URL bar.

You can see how POST data is sent on the Internet with [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for example.
Result will be something like that

```
http://127.0.0.1/pass.php
POST /pass.php HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/pass.php
Cookie: passx=87e8af376bc9d9bfec2c7c0193e6af70; PHPSESSID=l9hk7mfh0ppqecg8gialak6gt5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 30
username=zurfyx&pass=password
```

Where it says

```
Content-Length: 30
    username=zurfyx&pass=password
```

will be the post values.

Comment: Clarification: is `Content-Length` supposed to be `29` here? That's the actual length of the string `username=zurfyx&pass=password`.

Comment: @Hippo was a newline character meant to be there?

Comment: @vikingsteve I see what you mean. So I guess the Content always has a newline at the end of it, then.

Comment: The header is separated from body with extra newline

Answer (score 30):

The default media type in a POST request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is a format for encoding key-value pairs. The keys can be duplicate. Each key-value pair is separated by an `&` character, and each key is separated from its value by an `=` character.

For example:

```
Name: John Smith
Grade: 19
```

Is encoded as:

```
Name=John+Smith&Grade=19
```

This is placed in the request body after the HTTP headers.

Comment: You explained what we place in the HTTPBody, but what do we place/write in the HTTPHeader?

Comment: You mentioned tha the key can be duplicate, then what is the outcome of such a duplicate? Will the last one will automatically overwrite the previous value(s)? Thanks.

Comment: @JinghuiNiu if the key is duplicate it should be parsed as an array. 
This is very late but might help someone else.

Answer (score 21):

Form values in HTTP POSTs are sent in the request body, in the same format as the querystring.

For more information, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13).

Comment: "Same format" is a bit ambiguous. Do they begin with an `?` for example?

Comment: @CamiloMartin: No; in the same format as the contents of the querystring.  See the spec.

Comment: If you want to be really specific, read the RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-54

Comment: By the way, this answer is just as good as the other one, it actually says that the values go in the request body. and it provides the W3C spec.

Comment: @PeterWooster Yes, but doesn't provide an example. In that regard, is like an answer that says "look, there's an answer for your question in the application's blog *(link)*".

Comment: @PeterWooster It isn't needed, but it's very good when you forget something, google it, go to the first link which is SO, and there's a clear, concise example that tells you what you need instead of sending you to chew on the excessively-detailed specs that, even if comprehensive, may be unfit for refreshers. Think about it: most of the QAs on this site could boil down to "go read the spec/manual/API/etc *(link)*". Would it be useful? Not more than Google.

Comment: Only if the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not always the case.

Comment: The format of GET query string is different from that of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. For example, whitespace is encoded differently (%20 vs +). The answer is misleading in this regard.

Comment: Expanding on @Guffa's comment: Re *"in the same format as the querystring"* - that is only correct, if the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That is the *default*, but it is not *required*.

Answer (score 20):

Some of the webservices require you to place request *data* and *metadata* separately. For example a remote function may expect that the signed metadata string is included in a URI, while the data is posted in a HTTP-body.

The POST request may semantically look like this:

```
POST /?AuthId=YOURKEY&Action=WebServiceAction&Signature=rcLXfkPldrYm04 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/tab-separated-values; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: []
Host: webservices.domain.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

name    id
John    G12N
Sarah   J87M
Bob     N33Y
```

This approach logically combines QueryString and Body-Post using a single `Content-Type` which is a "parsing-instruction" for a web-server.

**Please note:** HTTP/1.1 is *wrapped* with the `#32` (space) on the left and with `#10` (Line feed) on the right.

Comment: The difference between `/user/john` and `/?user=john` is merely a semantic one (HTTP doesn't really give special treatment to query strings), so I take this as reasonably expected. But what do you mean by "wrapped by space on the left"? There aren't spaces before the HTTP method. You mean the blank line for post body?

Comment: There is a space (ASCII #32) between `...Ym04` and `HTTP/1.1` in the above code. So a QueryString simply resides between the verb and the protocol version.

Comment: Your note makes it sound like it's something unexpected and version-specific. Quite frankly it seems obvious there's a space there. And the line feed also applies to the other lines, like all things unix.

Comment: I just emphasized what I couldn't mark out in code. It may seem obvious but sometimes it is not.

Comment: It's true that we could pass the query parameters as part of the URL by separating the URI and the parameters with a `?` like we do with `GET` requests.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, let's differentiate between `GET` and `POST`

**Get:** It is the default `HTTP` request that is made to the server and is used to retrieve the data from the server and query string that comes after `?` in a `URI` is used to retrieve a unique resource.

this is the format

```
GET /someweb.asp?data=value HTTP/1.0
```

here `data=value` is the query string value passed.

**POST:** It is used to send data to the server safely so anything that is needed, this is the format of a `POST` request

```
POST /somweb.aspHTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded //you can put any format here
Content-Length: 11 //it depends
Name= somename
```

**Why POST over GET?**

In `GET` the value being sent to the servers are usually appended to the base URL in the query string,now there are 2 consequences of this

- The `GET` requests are saved in browser history with the parameters. So your passwords remain un-encrypted in browser history. This was a real issue for Facebook back in the days.
- Usually servers have a limit on how long a `URI` can be. If have too many parameters being sent you might receive `414 Error - URI too long`

In case of post request your data from the fields are added to the body instead. Length of request params is calculated, and added to the header for content-length and no important data is directly appended to the URL.

You can use the Google Developer Tools' network section to see basic information about how requests are made to the servers.

and you can always add more values in your `Request Headers` like `Cache-Control` , `Origin` , `Accept`.

Comment: The assumptions about security are only true in the context of a `HTTPS` connection, not `HTTP`.
`HTTPS` encrypts both the `URL` (including query params) and the `Request Body`, when `HTTP` encrypts/protects neither.
The issue described comes from the fact that many browsers store the `URIs` (including `URLs`) in their history databases (usually not encrypted).
So, use only the `Request Body`+`HTTPS` for anything sensitive.

Comment: @PetruZaharia I agree with your explanation. You can also suggest this as edit and I will be happy to accept! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways/formats of post parameters

- formdata
- raw data
- json
- encoded data
- file
- xml

They are controlled by content-type in Header that are representes as mime-types.

Comment: How does your answer expand or clarify any of the other answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

In CGI Programming on the World Wide Web the author says:

> Using the POST method, the server sends the data as an input stream to
> the program. ..... since the server passes information to this program
> as an input stream, it sets the environment variable CONTENT_LENGTH to
> the size of the data in number of bytes (or characters). We can use
> this to read exactly that much data from standard input.